# add new clientapplication to spring boot oauth2 server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am coding a Spring Boot application where I currently have a `@Configuration public class OAuthServerConfiguration` with an inner `protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` where I add support for a single OAuth2 client application.

I want to be able to add support for other client apps without restarting the application. Google is not helping much on this one. Does anybody know how to do it?

This is the relevant part of my current configuration (Check out the method `public void configure(ClentDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)` where I statically add the entry and configuration for the only client app this server authorizes). I am trying to figure out how to set it up and change it dynamically:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    ...

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        ...

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientappid")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                        .authorities("USER")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds("resourceid")
                        .secret("oauth2clientappsecret");
        }

        ...

    }

}
```